How do I know what a pyqtSignal will pass to a pyqtSlot?
I am going through the Qt doc page on Mode-View architecture and while trying to reproduce the usage of model indexes in PyQt5 I got to a working script that I don't fully understand. Here's the code:
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    path = '/path/to/dir/'

    model = QFileSystemModel()
    model.setRootPath(path)

    window = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
    label = QLabel("Files and Directories:\n")
    layout.addWidget(label)

    def link_data(directory):
        parent_index = model.index(directory)
        num_rows = model.rowCount(parent_index)

        names = []
        for row in range(num_rows):
            index = model.index(row, 0, parent_index)
            name = model.data(index)
            names.append(name)

        label.setText("Files and Directories:\n" + "\n".join(names))

    # Connect the directoryLoaded signal to the link_data slot
    model.directoryLoaded.connect(link_data)

    window.setWindowTitle("File System Model Data Retrieval")
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

It seems to me that model.directoryLoaded.connect(link_data) will enusre that, when the directoryLoaded signal is emitted, the root path of the model is passed to the link_data slot.
The C++ docs only say that void QFileSystemModel::directoryLoaded(const QString &path) is emitted when the gatherer thread has finished to load the path.
I want to understand how the directory argument from link_data(directory) gets filled, and how I can figure that from the docs.

The Python doc you're mentioning is derived from the generic python signal definition. In any case, you should always rely on the C++ docs. That said, it's unclear what you're actually asking: the signal documentation explains that the string of the argument refers to the directory that has been finally gathered, what part isn't clear about that? Note that slots only exist as class members (and of QObject subclasses), that decoretor there is completely useless.

Thanks for the reply, I'll drop the decorator and remove the generic pythong signal definition. I want to understand how the directory argument from link_data(directory) gets filled, and how I can figure that from the docs.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileSystemModel.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.directoryLoaded in the docs there is a section "Signals", click on the directoryLoaded signal to see the signature of the signal. It should tell you what you can expect as parameters for the slot.

So will the params in my signal always be what the slot is expecting?

@curioso the signal definition in the docs is a function with input parameters (i.e. the signature of the function) directoryLoaded(path) it also has this section: Parameters: path – str.  Since it is a signal definition you now know that this signal will emit a single parameter with type string. On the other side you need your slot function to match this signature and accept a single string argument.

@curioso Signals can have arguments, and if the argument exists it's always provided according to the specification of the documentation of that signal. Functions and/or slots connected to that signal should then always have as many positional arguments as the signal, or even less, but never more, unless they are keyworded. This means that link_data() could also have no argument at all; in your case there would be no point (as you do need that value), but sometimes you don't need it. For instance, the clicked signal of buttons always has a bool argument indicating the checked state of »

@curioso » button (even if it's not checkable, so it's always False in that case), but you normally just connect it to a function or method that doesn't need that argument. I suggest you to study the official Qt docs about signals & slots and check for some tutorials (like this). In any case, always refer to the C++ docs as first resource, not those of the Python bindings (not even the official "Qt for Python" ones) which should be checked only for specific cases related to Python.

@curioso How the argument gets filled is an implementation detail, so the docs won't mention it. Qt uses an internal class (QFileInfoGatherer) to gather all the information from the file-system as a background task. When this is finished, the model will have been fully populated, and the directoryLoaded signal can be emitted. This process will happen every time setRootPath is called, but exactly when (or even if) the signal is emitted is strictly indeterminate, since everything depends on an external resource (i.e. the local file-system).

@curioso Track from the QFileSystemModel::setRootPath() to QFileInfoGatherer::getFileInfos().
